# Only Vertices/Wireframe in Blender Render and Object Mode

Tags: rendering

I tried searching around for why this might be happening, I can only assume I hit some stupid hotkey at some point and didn't realize it. My issue is that my model is only displaying as its vertices in Blender Render and in the 3d Full View. I can see the wireframe in Object mode. It renders fine in Cycles for some reason, and in edit mode, I can see all the faces and whatnot perfectly fine. It's not an issue with Maximum Draw Type, as that is set to "textured".

**Render View and Object Mode**

[image: Render View and Object mode]

**3D Full View in Object Mode**
[image: 3d Full View]

**3D Full View in Edit Mode**
[image: 3d Full View in Edit]

Any help would be great! Sorry if this is a stupid question!

Answer (score 3):

[image]

You changed your material type to a HALO
In material settings, switch to a Surface type, and you'll be fine

Comment: Thank you! It seems I'd somehow set it to Halo, still not sure how that happened. I'd tried making a new surface material and assigning it to the model but for some reason it didn't work. I had to actually remove the halo material entirely for it to work.

Comment: @user15269 if this answer helped you please [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/278094).