# Show edges in render

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, vertices

I am trying to show the edges in my render but it is not working.

To see what I mean, I am trying to create the same result as the image below in Blender render.

Of course I did some research. I came across [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1829/is-it-possible-to-render-vertices-in-blender) question but when I follow the instructions of the answers, my objects just disappear if I render.

**So, is there somebody who can help me out with rendering the edges?**

[image: desired result]

Comment: Do you mean make the **edges** visible as in wireframe? related:  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10999/how-to-render-an-object-with-both-a-base-mesh-wireframe-and-subdivision-surface and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9177/wireframe-render-over-an-object-with-the-subdivision-surface-wireframe/9178#9178 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9271/render-a-wireframe-with-equal-thickness-in-cycles and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36701/how-to-get-solid-render-with-wireframes-and-no-shading

Comment: It you really mean vertices and not edges then look at this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33080/only-vertices-wireframe-in-blender-render-and-object-mode

Comment: @cegaton. Thanks for the links. Freestyle seems to be the best but it does not freestyle the inner lines like you can see here: http://puu.sh/obZk5/a3c2b19310.jpg . Any more suggestions?

Comment: Make your object or faces flat shaded and edges will show up. You can also make any specific edges visible by entering edit mode in your object, selecting desired edges pressing, Ctrl+E > Mark Freestyle. You can also control the Freestyle LineSet  to include more types of edge cases.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos.  Thanks. Found the LineSet panel and there I found the option I needed.